# ffmpeg append segments to m3u8 file without #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Every few seconds I'm receiving a chunk of a long audio file from a server. I want to segment those chunks and create a m3u8 playlist to play the audio in the browser.

I can create the m3u8 file and append segments every few seconds to it until I received the last chunk and the file can be played in the browser. The problem is that ffmpeg adds the `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` tag to the m3u8 file which adds short silence periods to the audio and the playback in the browser doesn't sound fluent.

Is there are way to tell ffmpeg that all my independent files actually belong together (same source and encoding) and stop adding the `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` tags? Or is there a way to avoid the short silence periods added by this tag? Or are there any other ways I can try to create a fluent audio stream from independent files?

My final m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXTINF:1.792000,
http://localhost:9000/aacf6dc4-9f3e-4f76-86b6-3e0f01a65d88000000.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:1.792000,
http://localhost:9000/aacf6dc4-9f3e-4f76-86b6-3e0f01a65d88000001.ts
...
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:1.792000,
http://localhost:9000/aacf6dc4-9f3e-4f76-86b6-3e0f01a65d88000006.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

My ffmpeg commands:

```
# create the playlist
ffmpeg -y -i <chunk.flac> -hls_playlist_type event -hls_base_url http://localhost:9000/ -hls_segment_filename <segment> -hls_time 2 -hls_flags omit_endlist playlist.m3u8 

# append to playlist
ffmpeg -y -i <chunk.flac> -hls_playlist_type event -hls_base_url http://localhost:9000/ -hls_segment_filename <segment> -hls_time 2 -hls_flags omit_endlist+append_list playlist.m3u8

# finish the playlist
ffmpeg -y -i <chunk.flac> -hls_playlist_type event -hls_base_url http://localhost:9000/ -hls_segment_filename <segment> -hls_time 2 -hls_flags append_list playlist.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code of `libavformat/hlsenc.c`:

```
if (hls->flags & HLS_APPEND_LIST) {
            parse_playlist(s, vs->m3u8_name, vs);
            vs->discontinuity = 1;
```

As soon as you use `append_list` a discontinuity is inserted. Unless you add an option and patch ffmpeg - I don't think you can avoid the `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` tag.

But you could post process the playlist using a simple command line:

```
grep -v "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY" playlist.m3u8 > temp; mv temp playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: I already tried to manually remove the tags but then the player stops playing after the first segment.